# How to modify the text that a keyboard button echoes on to the screen in windows?

Tags: scripting, systems-programming

The idea behind this is to use a key combination in order to echo a very frequently used string. Say shift+backspace must echo to the screen "Thank you". I don't know where to start and what exactly to do. I have experience in programming(C/C++/Java) but I am totally new to scripting. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why scripting? Presumably, to do this, you would need to write a daemon/service that monitors the keyboard's input: I think that would be a whole lot easier in a system language like C/C++... Anyway, I believe there's software available that already does this -- can't remember what it's called -- so at least you know it's possible!

Comment: That sounds a lot easier Xophmeister, is there anyway I could get started with writing such daemons?

Comment: No idea! Try Googling for how to write Windows services... Note that I assume you want to affect the whole system -- i.e., pressing your desired key combination in any application is captured and reinterpretted by your service -- if it's just for a specific application, however, then this approach would be a bit overkill!

Comment: (Sorry: I assumed Windows for some reason!... Still, same advice for *nixes: just replace "service" with "daemon")

Comment: It is for the whole system alright, and yeah it is targeted at Windows OS for the time being. Tried googling, but there seem to be no tutorials on daemons and stuff to a person completely new to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write a Windows service, but [these links](http://bit.ly/OYpdHb) seem pretty accessible; especially for someone with C/C++ system programming experience.

If that's no good: [it's been done](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It's open source, so if you want to implement something similar yourself, their [source repo](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey) is on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Xophmeister, <a href="http://www.pcworld.com/downloads/file/fid,65010/description.html">PhraseExpress</a> did the trick more or less.